# Is Cohen's h appropiate to compare two different F1 scores?

Tags: t-test, effect-size

I recently learnt about Cohen's h and its used in power analysis. I wondered if using this metric for comparing two different F1 scores is adequate.

If I have two models with two different F1 scores, suppose I have several measurements due to cross validation, which of the following approaches is the proper one?

1. Using a paired t-test for the two F1 samples
2. Computing the Cohen's h and perform a one-tailed t-test to see if it is significantly larger than 0.2
3. Compute the mean (or median) of each sample and keep the model with the highest value

I also read about the "no free lunch theorem", I do not fully understand it but it seems like doing complex manipulations does not improve the validity of the decision.